# Pluggable UI Components for Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms

Our application contains many modules which could be dynamically pushed to the our application after it is installed and running. All those modules might require some display at the UI.  So I am thinking that we could build a UI exe which could load UI component from a DLL (or any other type of assembly). Let's say module1 and module2 are active at the machine, we would display a "module1" and "module2" at the left frame of the UI. If user clicks on "module1", the right frame would open the screen for module1 which is loaded from the another assembly (such as DLLs) which is pushed down together with module1.

Just wonder if this pluggable UI architecture is even possible at the Windows Form or not. I did some search on internet and I didn't find any useful information around this.

Comment: Although "Smart Client Software Factory" and CAB are retired now, they provide everything you mention and more. You should invest some time to study them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648753.aspx

Comment: thanks for the information. By the way, I think that my question is a valid question. I don't understand why it is marked for close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible and I have done this my self.

The best way to do this is you create a 2nd DLL outside of the program. Inside that DLL you define a interface that your plugin will implement. You then make your form in the main EXE load all the DLL's in a directory and see if it contains any classes that implement that interface. In your plugin DLL's you also reference the same DLL and have your modules implement that interface. Any functions you want common to all of your Plugins you need to put in to `IMyPlugin` as that is the interface you will be casting everything to in your UI so only those functions will be visible.

```
//In a 2nd project that compiles as a DLL
public interface IMyPlugin
{
    Control GetControl();
}

///////////////////

//In your main project
private List<IMyPlugin> pluginsList;   

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    foreach(string pluginPath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"\Plugins\", "*.dll"))
    {
        try
        {
            //load the assembly
            Assembly pluginAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(pluginPath);

            //Find all types defined in the assembly.
            Type[] types = pluginAssembly.GetTypes();

            //Filter the types to only ones that implment IMyPlugin
            var plugins = types.Where(x => typeof(IMyPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(x));

            //Filter the plugins to only ones that are createable by Activator.CreateInstance
            var constructablePlugins = plugins.Where(x => !x.ContainsGenericParameters && x.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null);

            foreach (var pluginType in constructablePlugins)
            {
                //instantiate the object
                IMyPlugin plugin = (IMyPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType);

                pluginsList.Add(plugin);
            }
        }
        catch (BadImageFormatException ex)
        {
            //ignore this exception -- probably a runtime DLL required by one of the plugins..
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MainForm.MainForm_Load()");
        }
    }

    //Suspend the layout for the update
    this.SuspendLayout();
    this.someFlowLayoutPanelToStoreMyPlugins.SuspendLayout();

    foreach(IMyPlugin plugin in pluginsList)
    {
        this.someFlowLayoutPanelToStoreMyPlugins.Controls.Add(plugin.GetControl());
    }
    //resume the layout
    this.someFlowLayoutPanelToStoreMyPlugins.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.someFlowLayoutPanelToStoreMyPlugins.PerformLayout();
    this.ResumeLayout();
}


//////////////////////


// In your plugin DLL.

public class Plugin : UserControl, IMyPlugin
{
    public Plugin()
    {
        //The code in the main form requires there be a public 
        //  no parameter constructor (either explicitly or implicitly),
        //  UserControls usually have one anyway for InitializeComponent.

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Control GetControl()
    {
        return this;
    }

    // The rest of your code.
}
```

Note: This code was just copying and pasting a lot of my code, I don't know if it will work perfectly as is, but this will get you close to where you need to go.

Comment: thanks for the info, I think that it gives me direction where to go next

Answer (score 1):

This is quite possible, and it's not specific to WinForms. You'll need a way of asking the module to give its UI to you at some point. For ex: your modules will implement an interface, and it will have a method that returns a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e63s4df3.aspx). When you call this, you can do what ever with it on your UI.

For ex: your right panel can be something that can host a Panel.

Your Interface can look like follows

```
interface IModule
{
    ...
    Panel GetUI();
    ...
}
```

So, when the user clicks the module in the left pane, you would run something like this.

```
var selectedModule = GetSelectedModule() 
// this method will do the Reflection to load your assemblies, 
// go through the Types, filter every type that implement IModule and load them.
// then get an instance of the module. (Let me know if you want help on Reflection)

if (!GetConfiguration().IsModuleEnables(selectedModule))
    return; // module not enabled. Ignore click ???

rightPane.Children.Clear();
rightPane.Children.Add(selectedModule.GetUI());
// might want to dock the module as 'Fill' as well.
```

I think you're better off keeping the 'Is Active' state for a module in your application, than asking a module whether it is enabled (where a rogue module can return true all the time.)

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:** To keep things secure, I recommend you load the modules into a separate [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx). Although you might have issues passing UI objects between them.

Comment: The problem with keeping it in the application is that you still need to recompile the application (or at least push a new config file) every time you want a new module.

Comment: yeah, need a config file or some other sort of storing which components are active/enabled. I assumed he had some sort of a settings screen to enable and disable components.

Comment: thanks. the modules would be enabled based on license key and enabled by the customer admin. User doesn't  have control for it. The active module list would be queried dynamically on startup.

Comment: In that case, instead of `GetConfiguration().IsModuleEnabled(...)` check your licese, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, so I can't guarantee that it'll work, but from what I've seen, it ought to.

If the list of modules is known when you build the exe, it should be trivial to update the functionality of any component by just updating the component dll.  If you include some way to toggle from within the dll whether or not a given component is active, you can "pad" the dll with dummy components which you later add functionality for.  For example:

```
using ComponentLibrary;
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    //...
    if (Module1.IsActive()) listModules.Add(Library.Module1);
    if (Module2.IsActive()) listModules.Add(Library.Module2);
  }
  listModules_click()
  {
     // var m = clicked-on-module
     if (m is Module1)
     {
       component = new Module1();
     }
     else if (m is Module2)
     {
       component = new Module2();
     }
  }
}

namespace ComponentLibrary
{
  abstact class Module : Component
  {
     public abstract bool IsActive();
  }
  public class Module1 : Module
  {
     public bool IsActive() { return true; }
  }
  public class Module2 : Module
  {
     public bool IsActive() { return false; }
  }  
}
```

Later, you code Module2, and replace it's `IsActive()` result with `true`.  But the signature doesn't change, so you don't need to recompile the exe.  Until then, there's no way to actually pull up Module2.

Comment: thanks for it. I just want to know how to load the UI code from a DLL and how to place it generically at the exe. However what you said here is valid as well.